# Upload To Blob Storage With Javascript(Client Browser) With SAS

Tags: javascript, azure, file-upload, blob, blobstorage

I'm trying to implement an HTML controller in my webapp that will upload files from the client to my azure blob storage.

I know how to do it in the server side with C# but this solution isn't right for me because i'm dealing with a large volume files(that the client uploads), so I don't want to upload them to my server side, I want that the client will upload them straight to the blob storage.

but here is where I'm lost, maybe you could help me.

Objective: I need to grant SAS for that user.
Solution: I call(using AJAX) to a server side method that generate the string (string - URL + SAS token)

Now all is left to do is split the files to chunks and upload them giving the URL with the token that I generate on the server side.

I read a lot of article about it but every article says different things, half of them was in the period that azure was not supporting CORS, so a huge amount of them out of date.

How can I do the last two things in the right way :
1.Chunk the file.
2.Upload the file.

One last thing i read in some article that i need to split the file to chunks and then upload all the chunks and then to commit or something all the chunks so its become one file in the storage.(maybe i got it in the worng way)

anyway if somebody could help me with guidelines or anything that will help me overcome this two last jobs needed to be done

*Update:

The errors I get(1.OPTION 2. headers):
Open the image in a new tab to see it properly 
[image]

*Update 2:
This is how i set the CORS:

[image]

Comment: Try this link: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/. HTH.

Comment: Gaurav I have two question for you:
1.based on your article:
http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/ I didnt understand when I configure the CORS ?
I know that in order to upload i need to set premission first with SAS and with that URL upload the blob, but when the CORS code should run ? 
and there anyway to get the origin of the client programmatic without specific it in the allow origin ?
Your articles are great man!

Comment: 1) You would need to configure CORS before and it would be a one time deal i.e. once you configure CORS, you don't have to do it for every request. 2) I'm not sure what you mean. Are you allowing access to your blob storage from any random URL?

Comment: If I have a web application that user upload files to my blob storage, I don't need to configure origin for each user(his IP) ? or just configure origin to my web application ?

Comment: That's right. You just have to configure origin to your web application.

Comment: Oh ok now i understand...
One last problem i'm facing:
I keep getting the this error :
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:2620' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403."

I did everything like you wrote in the article, and i keep getting this error...chrome, firefox and etc..

There any chance you know what causes this problem ?
its ok if i send you an email ?

Comment: I post to my orginal question the two errors i get, maybe you formiller with that.
Thanks agian @GauravMantri

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you would need to add the port as well in your allowed origin. Can you please try with http://localhost:2620?

Comment: I added another picture to my original question that show the CORS configuration, as you can see the port is there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64338/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-ron).

Comment: can you please tell me the way you did multiple files upload instead of single file upload (in @GauravMantri blog), if at all you did? Also did you also split the SAS URI and appended blobID and alll, like gaurav did in his blog?

Comment: @ApurvG Yes exactly like that, with SAS and Client Upload from his browser, else the user will need to upload it to the Server and from there to the Blob Storage (Double the work).

Comment: @Ron How to tackle multiple file upload? Thanks for responding.

Comment: @ApurvG I've implemented it 3 years ago, I need to go over the code and recall what I did there exatcly.. Ill update my questions with an answer soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ron. Waiting for your update